# npm init automatically create etc directory and `--save-dev` doesn't work

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, package.json

When I use `npm init` in cmd, npm creates an etc directory and package.json.
Then when I use `npm install stylus --save-dev`,the module is downloaded in node_modules directory. But I can not find dependency in package.json
and I realize I can use command `ls`, `mkdir` in cmd, which is also confusing.

after npm init I `cat package.json`

[image: cat package.json]

This is my initial directory after I use `npm init`, I get `etc\` directory, which should not be in this directory

[image: etc\ directory]

This is the directory after I use `npm install stylus --save-dev`

[image: after <code>npm install stylus --save-dev</code>]

After installing stylus, I `cat package.json`, but no dependency in this file

[image: no dependency in this file]

I cannot find out what is wrong.

I'm using Windows 10

```
node-version 8.9.1
npm version 5.5.1
npx installed
```

Comment: You should work  a bit on your question, describe what you are showing in the images, and maybe post your entire code

Comment: Thanks for your advise.i will modify my question.

Comment: please format your question properly. There must be a space after punctuations except for open brackets which have a space before

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
npm install -D stylus
```

or

```
npm install stylus -D
```

For multiple packages, do this:

```
npm install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 -S
```

or

```
npm install -S pkg1 pkg2 pkg3
```

The difference between `-S` and `-D` is `-S` adds the package(s) to dependencies while `-D` adds to dev-dependencies.

`-S` and `-D` are flags, regardless of where you put it, be it before the package names or after the package names, npm will recognise them and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much,but it doesn't work.I recall --save-dev seems to work before i install npx.And i think package is not installed correctly,because i get stylus.cmd in the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this command

```
npm install --save-dev stylus
```

When you write stylus then `--save-dev` it is identifying `--save-dev` as package not as command.

For multiple package to install we write

```
npm install package1 package2 package3
```

Comment: That make sence to you . Working.

Comment: Thanks for your help,But it doesn't work.It still doesn't create dependency in package.json.

Comment: Delete the dependency first which is alredy install then install again . Let me know what you get

Comment: when i use ls command,i get etc/  node_modules/  package.json  stylus*  stylus.cmd .There is still no dependency in package.json.I ask some people,and i realize i can use ls command or mkdir command in cmd.Maybe it has something to do with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. I assume that you would have set "prefix" key for npm local configuration. Running:
    `npm config delete prefix`
may help. Then start your project:
    `npm init` or `npm init -y`